# How to access new user defined DAC

Tags: acumatica

I'm having an issue, I created a custom table, added it to my customization project as a new DAC. The code is there, but how do i call this in a graph? I tried instantiating it as its own object, tried performing a pxselect, creating it as a viewname. None have worked for me, I looked through the documentation for "Generating a Data Access Class" And that doesn't apply to the ERP framework i get errors trying to generate class via that process.

Any ideas on how i should implement the new DAC to be accessible in my graph?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, I incorrectly called my PXselect initially.

```
public PXSelect<UsrKSPOReceiptWeightSplit> WeightSplits;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Take your extension class from the AppRuntimeCode folder and cut/paste to your VS project folder.  From there you can access your custom fields etc.  Today in the Acumatica framework this is the procedure until this is fixed in the future.  In the T300 manual this is covered in detail.

Here's a summary:
1. In Customization Mgr - create your data extensions
2. In VS copy the files that CM creted to your project to get a reference
3. Compile your extension library
4. When publishing your project you will have to delete your Customization extensions because there will be duplicates when you created your extension lib in VS.